# How do I post a new entry into Elasticsearch with a custom set version number?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

According to the [Elastic search site](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/optimistic-concurrency-control.html)

```
PUT /website/blog/2?version=5&version_type=external
```

Now, the issue is that in the above example it expects you to provide the ID for the record on the insertion.
What I need is Elasticsearch to set the id but allow me to set the version number.
I've tried the PUT and variations of it but it fails.

Can someone help me figure out if/how to do this?

1. PUT a new record into Elasticsearch.
2. Elasticsearch set the id
3. Allows me to set the version at time of insertion

Comment: curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/playground/equipment/1" -d ' { "type": "slide", "quantity": 2 }' https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-interact-with-data-in-elasticsearch-using-crud-operations

Comment: That looks like the call for inserting an entry and providing the ID for it. I need Elasticsearch to specify the ID and allow me to set the version number.

Comment: What I want is for Elasticsearch to create the ID but let me specify the version number.  Is this possible?